# Unity - How to instantiate new object with initial properties (like velocity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm trying to implement a tower defense game in Unity, and I can't figure out how can I assign a velocity or a force to a new instantiated object (in the creator object's script)
I have a tower which is supposed to shoot a bullet towards the enemy which triggered its collider. This is the script of the towers:

```
function OnTriggerEnter(other:Collider){
if(other.name=="Enemy")
{
ShootBulletTo(other.transform);
}
}

function ShootBulletTo(target:Transform)
{//public var Bullet:Transform
var BulletClone = Instantiate(Bullet,transform.position, Quaternion.identity); // ok
BulletClone.AddForce(target.position); //does not compile since Transform.AddForce() does not exist.
}
```

I guess the problem is I have to use a `Transform` variable for instantiate but I need a `GameObject` variable for velocity, force etc. So how can I instantiate the bullet with initial velocity? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to acces the rigidbody component of your bullet clone to change the force, not the transform.

Here's how your code should look:

```
function OnTriggerEnter(other:Collider)
{
    if(other.name=="Enemy")
    {
       ShootBulletTo(other.transform);
    }
}

function ShootBulletTo(target:Transform)
{
    var Bullet : Rigidbody;
    BulletClone = Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    BulletClone.AddForce(target.position); 
}
```

There's also a good example in the unity script reference
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

[EDIT] I'm pretty sure, that you don't want to add the enemies position as a force, instead you should add a direction that goes towards the enemies position.
You subtract two positions to gain a direction vector between them, so the ShootBulletTo function should look like this:

```
function ShootBulletTo(target:Transform)
{
    // Calculate shoot direction
    var direction : Vector3;
    direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

    // Instantiate the bullet
    var Bullet : Rigidbody;
    BulletClone = Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    // Add force to our bullet
    BulletClone.AddForce(direction); 
}
```